# How to find the sum of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is $1\cdot\frac{1}{2} + 2\cdot\frac{1}{4} + 3\cdot\frac{1}{8} + \cdots$

Or in other words

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$$

What kind of series is this and how to find the sum? Thanks....

Comment: Hint. Differentiate the power series for $1/(1-x)$, then multiply by $x$.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! Why don't you do it and I'll give you a lovely green check mark :)

Comment: I think the third term should have $\frac18$.

Comment: @martycohen fixed thanks.

Comment: Nice accepted answer so I won't post mine. It's a good technique to remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without calculus:

If
$s(a)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} na^n
$
for
$|a| < 1$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
as(a)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} na^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)a^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n}\\
&=s(a)-\dfrac{a}{1-a}\\
\text{so}\\
s(a)
&=\dfrac{a}{(1-a)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you. I am a little confused by one thing. You  have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n} = a/(1-a)$ but I thought that it was $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n}$ that summed to that?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n} = 1/(1-a)$. $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a^{n} = a^k/(1-a)$.

Comment: Aha. Thanks again.